# How to use deluxetable.sty?

Tags: tables, report, tutorials, physics, deluxetable

I'm writing a lab report and it was recommended to use the deluxetable package, which is used by physics journals, etc. Despite the popularity of it, I am having trouble finding any tutorial on it. Can anyone briefly explain how to use deluxetable, i.e the structure and options available?

Thank you.

Comment: Execute `texdoc deluxetable` on a command line. Additionally, you might want to click on the `deluxetable` tag under your question to see related questionns and answers.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have already checked questions with the tag. I'm talking about the actual code structure, like between the \begin and \end. How do I define the columns? How do I put the cell entries? etc. I'm very new. Started Latex less than 2 months ago. That also means I don't know what executing texdoc means.

Comment: @Zachary For information on how to execute `texdoc` see [Class and Package Documentation](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/texdoc.html). If you're using Windows, there should be a GUI version which you can access through the Start menu in your TeX distribution's folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure is similar to a regular table with a few exceptions such as column headers.

A simple table:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{deluxetable}

\begin{document}

\begin{deluxetable}{cccccccc}

\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablewidth{0pt}

 \tablecaption{ Sample Title \label{tab:sample}}

 \tablehead{
 \colhead{Head 1} & \colhead{Head 2} & \colhead{Head 3} & \colhead{Head 4}& \colhead{Head 5} & \colhead{Head 6} &\colhead{Head 7}& \colhead{Head 8}
 }

 \startdata 

 sample 1 & sample 2 & sample 3 & sample 4 & sample 5 & sample 6 & sample 7 & sample 8\\

 \enddata

 \vspace{-0.5cm}
 \tablecomments{sample comment}

\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful. Is there also a way to make a deluxe table two columns?

Comment: @Zachary yes, just change `\begin{deluxetable}{cccccccc}` to `\begin{deluxetable}{cc}`. The data will also have to be two columns as well (only one & per line).

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant is there a way to have the deluxe table split into two columns, as if my document were two columns. Also, if I change the tablewidth values, I keep getting an error on the startdata line, what's going on there?